# Flutter Unit test: Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mocking, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to mock a stream in my unit test (using mocktail) that comes from a third-party library:

This my test code:

```
void main() {
  late AirPodsMotionProvider airPodsMotionProvider;
  final mockDeviceMotionData = DeviceMotionDataMocks();

  setUp(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    airPodsMotionProvider = AirPodsMotionProvider();
  });

  group('test AirPodsMotionProvider', () {
    group('test listenForAirPodsMotionData', () {
      test('test listen for incoming data', () async {
        final value = mockDeviceMotionData.mockDefaultDeviceMotionData;

        when(
          () => airPodsMotionProvider.listenForAirPodsMotionData(),
        ).thenAnswer((_) => Stream<DeviceMotionData>.value(value));

        airPodsMotionProvider.listenForAirPodsMotionData().listen(
          expectAsync1(
            (event) {
              expect(event, value);
            },
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I have written a provider which wraps the third party's library functionality called AirPodsMotionProvider and it looks like this:

```
class AirPodsMotionProvider {
  Stream<DeviceMotionData> listenForAirPodsMotionData() =>
      FlutterAirpods.getAirPodsDeviceMotionUpdates;
}
```

My question is how can I make the stream return the stream with a specific value.
I read some answers mentioning I need to do something like:

```
class MockFlutterAirpods extends Mock implements FlutterAirPods {}
```

And then make that function return a specific function, but it didn't work for me exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `airPodsMotionProvider` must be a mock, this `Mock` child class so that you will be able to stub its methods with `when`.

So you need a mocked class:

```dart
class MockAirPodsMotionProvider extends Mock implements AirPodsMotionProvider {}
```

and then in your `setUp` you initialize your `airPodsMotionProvider` with such class - `MockAirPodsMotionProvider`.

The further call to `when` will then work as expected. But what you do in this test is you actually test the mock. You may want to pass this mock to a class that depends on the `AirPodsMotionProvider` to test this class's behavior, not the mock itself, as it's just a mock. It doesn't have the logic of what it mocks.

Comment: This helped me to test the cubit, but how can I test this specific provider? As you said this would not really test the provider, but the mock, so I need mock the third party library somehow